# How can I use checkboxlisttile in alertDialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem when I am trying to use a checkboxlisttile in an alertdialog. I can see the list tile, but it doesn't change anything when I click on that, there won't be a tick.

```
bool imp = false
Future _showAlert(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  child: AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Add'),
    content: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text('Important:'),
            value: imp,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                imp = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - DropdownButtonFormField value not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600319/flutter-dropdownbuttonformfield-value-not-updating)

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676334/update-checkbox-and-return-value-from-dialog-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add this 2 lines to your onchange method

```
    onChanged: (value) {

                  setState(() {
                    imp = value;
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Line 1
                  _showAlert(context) ;// Line 2
                },
```

Comment: Bad approach, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52684999/4693979